# How to provide the password for Spawn Child_Process in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, child-process, spawn

I am trying to create a mysql backup of my application using mysqldump. The spawn child process seems unable to write the password. These are all the things I have tried so far.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn("mysqldump",
["-u", "Username", 
"DBName", 
">", "./Backup/DB_Backup.sql", 
"-p", "Password"]);

spawn.stdin.write("P");
spawn.stdin.write("a");
spawn.stdin.write("s");
spawn.stdin.write("s");
spawn.stdin.write("w");
spawn.stdin.write("o"); 
spawn.stdin.write("r");
spawn.stdin.write("d");
spawn.stdin.write("\n");

spawn.stdin.write("Password\n");

spawn.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    spawn.stdin.write("Password\n");
});

spawn.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

spawn.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

The question may seem like a duplicate but none of the answers helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"-p", "Password"` on `"-pPassword"`

Example:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const mysqldump = spawn('mysqldump', [
    '-u', db.user,
    '-p' + db.password,
    db.database
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this:

```
        const DATABASE_NAME = 'test'
        let wstream = fs.createWriteStream(`./backup/${DATABASE_NAME}.sql`);
        let mysqldump = spawn('mysqldump', [
            `--host=${process.env.MYSQL_HOST}`,
            `--port=${process.env.MYSQL_PORT}`,
            `--user=${process.env.MYSQL_USER}`,
            `--password=${process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD}`,
            DATABASE_NAME
        ])
        mysqldump
            .stdout
            .pipe(wstream)
            .on('finish', function () {
                console.log('Completed')
            })
            .on('error', function (err) {
                console.error(err)
            })
```